# Как при каждой записи в файл прибавлять к индексу записываемого в файл списка 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть недописанный код:

```py
if ui.checkBox_4.isChecked():
        user_names = []
        passwords = []
        mails = []

        input_data = open('acc_pass_email.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().split('\n')

        for line in input_data:
            splitted_line = line.split(':')
            user_names.append(splitted_line[0])#import1
            passwords.append(splitted_line[1])#import2
            mails.append(splitted_line[2])#import3
        while int(gf) >= 1:
            if ui.checkBox_4.isChecked():
                sv = ["1","1","1","1","1","1"]
                sv[0] = #import1
                sv[2] = #import2
                sv[4] = #import3
                sv[5] = ("_______________")
                file = ui.lineEdit_6.text() + '''/collage_random_answer.txt'''
                with open(str(file), 'a') as filehandle:
                        for listitem in sv:
                            filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

И файл acc_pass_email.txt:

```
Taichtamuu:z5US6pqrGiH7MhU:Lafapanone1992@rambler.ru
Keaksagimi:jMMZwDViXa85XtG:Vepebnapno1995@rambler.ru
Liepnalot:gsUvuX8catlVoRI:Kosamnanel2001@rambler.ru
Gevimnyuov:rlnYy4vEk6kLthA:Luteltabmi2005@rambler.ru
Siihzidari:pS8HvYg6lQAyUcp:Levabalane1990@rambler.ru
Keebapitn:VVHW3MD9oX4u7ox:Nezashalol1988@rambler.ru
Haupavpana:7PKUSslyhHsDQfH:Vaesakalfi1995@rambler.ru
Koynzunvhi:OLiPYprK69jLdI5:Deakapiin2004@rambler.ru
Kaalanaif:LoIUhYZ8MjIwN8n:Manibneul1980@rambler.ru
Zaasramkno:q2vzu4W2rHncYjv:Zhezabzhan2000@rambler.ru
```

На выходе в файле /collage_randomanswer.txt я хочу получить это:

```
Taichtamuu
z5US6pqrGiH7MhU
Lafapanone1992@rambler.ru
__
Keaksagimi
gsUvuX8catlVoRI
Vepebnapno1995@rambler.ru
__
Liepnalot
gsUvuX8catlVoRI
Kosamnanel2001@rambler.ru
__
```

и т.д.

Comment: Зачем было удалять вопрос на который уже был дан ответ? Создавать новый аккаунт и прочее. Более того, в этот вопрос вы скопировали код, который был указан в ответе к удаленному Вами вопросу. Более того, краткий вопрос совершенно не соостветствует тому, что вы написали в основном теле вопроса.

Comment: @Mus1k Вопрос уже другой просто в нем есть кусок кода из прошлого ответа